# Why checking for iframe parent function returns true when no iframes involved?

Tags: javascript, iframe

This is the scenario: we have a *x.html* page that could be loaded as a "standalone" page or as frame of another page *y.html* (same domain). Both pages have a function called **setDirtyFlag()** that just sets an internal flag to *true* or *false*. When *x* is loaded inside a *y* iframe, it should also set the parent dirty flag with the same value. This is the code for *x* and *y* pages:

**x.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var setDirtyFlag=function(val) {
        isDirty = val;
        if (window.parent && window.parent.setDirtyFlag)
          window.parent.setDirtyFlag(val);
      }
      setDirtyFlag(true);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    This is the iframe
  </body>
</html>
```

**y.html**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      var setDirtyFlag = function(val) {
        alert('dirty flag set');
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <iframe src="x.html"></iframe>
  </body>
</html>
```

You can create two files in a folder and load *y.html* without problems, you will see an alert saying that dirty flag has been set. But if you load *x.html* apparently everithing is ok, but the script is entering in a recursive loop that will finish when the browser exceeds its capacity. You can see it by adding an alert inside the `if (window.parent && window.parent.setDirtyFlag)`:

```
        if (window.parent && window.parent.setDirtyFlag) {
          alert("again");
          window.parent.setDirtyFlag(val);
        }
```

Why *window.parent* is defined even if the page is not inside an iframe? And why it contains a reference to the functions in this frame? And the most important, how to make it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a window does not have a parent, the "parent" property is a reference to itself.

You can just check to see if `window.parent == window`.

Comment: Ok, do you know if there is any compatibility issue with this among browsers?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's basic JavaScript semantics, so aside from truly ancient (and ignorable) browsers like Netscape 3 you're probably safe. (And note that I don't actually *know* of any problems in any browsers. It should be pretty quick to set up a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) to test it.)